# Object detection by color

Tags: networking, raspicam, performance

I just started planning a project including the raspberry pi . I have experience in programming but never used a pi before. In my project I want to do object detection by color. I need to classify the objects by theire different colors on multiple conveyor belts. On each belt only one object will pass because its only wide enough for one object.

My problem is that I dont know how to realize my project. Is one camera enough for lets say 2 belts or should I use one camera for each belt ? If yes a pi can only have one camera or should I use cameras with USB ports? If no I need to use 2 pi's and deal with connecting them. The problem with cameras with USB ports is that I cant judge if they will be fast enough to deal with a bigger throughput.
That are my first thoughts. Maybe you can help me deciding how to realize my project.

Update:

I found a pretty good blog with some interesting thoughts

[Multiple cameras with the Raspberry Pi and OpenCV](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/18/multiple-cameras-with-the-raspberry-pi-and-opencv/)

Comment: Welcome to the site. There are *a lot* of things going on in your question - by my count we're looking at a minimum of 5 separate issues, some of which are pretty big topics. Your question is too broad to be easily answerable in a limited amount of space, and is veering into non-Raspberry Pi territory in places. Consider splitting it into sections, determine which parts are relevant here, check for existing questions, then post each remaining issue as a separate, smaller question.

Comment: yeah you are right maybe :P I will split the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look to this tutorial!

Computer vision is an exciting but intricate technology

http://www.open-electronics.org/computer-vision-with-raspberry-pi-and-the-camera-pi-module/

Good luck!

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.